# Not able to connect to external sites on Cisco Anyconnect using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, internet, 20.04, vpn, cisco

I am using Cisco AnyConnect Mobility Client 4.5.02033 on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I try to connect to the company's network it is working fine but as soon as I open any external website, (example: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) it doesn't open them.

Can someone please help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally contacted the network admins and they informed me that I need to put "Wpad" as network proxy and that solved my problem.